# Installing Software Error in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, sdk, installation

I'm wanna install new software in eclipse luna version, but it has error during the installation!
The error is:

```
An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
Error reading signed content.
error in opening zip file
```

What should I've done?
Please help me.

Comment: How are you proceeding for your installation? Marketplace website? Marketplace inside Eclipse? Update site? Manual deployment? And which plugin are you trying to install?

Comment: @Alexis Dufrenoy: I downloaded eclipse from eclipse marketplace...
And I try to install ADT-23.0.4 plugin in eclipse but I can't because of this error...

Comment: What I wanted to know is: how are you installing ADT? Do you follow the instruction found on the official site? http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: For installing, I go to Help ---> Install new software ---> click on Archive button ---> Select ADT form my computer ---> And install it

Comment: Yes, I follow android developer installation method...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are trying to install ADT using the update site, as indicated on the official ADT page [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html). Try to install it using the Eclipse marketplace.

Go to the [ADT page on the marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/android-development-tools-eclipse#.VDP-iil_vUQ), and just drag and drop the "Install" icon on your running Eclipse. Then follow the instructions.

Comment: Thanks. Why can't they post this way on developer.android.com?